# Which site in stack exchange family is recommended for 'smart wifi plugs' and 'Google Home'?

Tags: discussion

I'm going to have various questions about our new 'Google Home' speech-based assistant, in regard to finding compatible 'smart wifi socket plugs' and setting them up.

So, I'm wondering which site within 'stack exchange family' is the preferred place to ask such questions.  Any recommendations?

TIA...

Comment: You could try [r/googlehome](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/)

Comment: maybe [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/)? They have a [google-home tag](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-home?mixed=1). Though I'm not sure how they feel about "shop for me" or compatibility type questions. Might be worth asking in their [meta](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the appropriate site is [Internet of Things SE](https://iot.stackexchange.com/). In the future, we may also have a [Google SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115799/google).